# Notifying an activity that it needs to make an update

Tags: android

I've read that it's bad practice for an activity in the foreground to try to communicate/manipulate an activity in the background, and that generally the onResume function should be used.

So I've got one activity that lets a user add a "favorite" thing.  There's another activity that shows a list of all the favorited things.  Instead of querying the DB and rebuilding the list each time onResume, I'm using a class with just static flags like "favorites_updated", and if it's true, onResume we do the extra work - if it's false we don't bother.

This feels a little clunky - is there a more established way of doing something like this?

TYIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also create a listner for the change in favorite list in background activity and on change you can notify your back activity.

This method has an advantage as you don't have code a lot of changes in onResume.

Comment: how would that work? (I'm in my first week in the Android environment) Wouldn't a listener require a reference between Activities?  Do you have some psuedo-code or a link or something that'd illustrate the premise?

Comment: Create a listner say FavoriteChangeListner with method notifyChage(params) . Then Implement this listner in your Activity where you want implement changes .

Comment: Create a listner say FavoriteChangeListner with method notifyChage(params) . Then Implement this listner in your Activity where you want implement changes . After that Register to the listner and from child activity when require call notifyChage(params) on parent activty . I will post the code as soon as possible. Please go through [link](http://tseng-blog.nge-web.net/blog/2009/02/17/how-implement-your-own-listener-android-java/ ) .

Comment: this looks promising - i'll post back and accept if it works.  thx

Answer (score 0):

If you always navigate from ListActivity -> FavoritesActivity, you could launch the FavoritesActivity from ListActivity using

```
startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode) .
```

If the user changes there favorites, pass a boolean 'updated' back using

```
 setResult (int resultCode, Intent data)
```

then retrive it in the ListActivites

```
 onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

If the boolean is true, re-query your cursor.

Another option would be to update a SharedPreference that you write in FavoritesActivity and later read in your ListActivity (much like static-variable).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Actually, I never launch the ListActivity from the activity to add an item to that list.  So the static flag thing is probably as close as I'm going to get?

Comment: Yes, but consider using SharedPreferences instead of static variables, sense they can be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

I use get/putExtras to pass additional parameters with Intent when starting an activity. Though, since the current question is more about preserving a persistent state across activities, than about message passing, I would +1 shared preferences, vs a static variable.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref
http://www.balistupa.com/blog/2009/08/passing-data-or-parameter-to-another-activity-android/

Answer (score 0):

Create a listner say FavoriteChangeListner with method notifyChage(params) . Then Implement this listner in your Activity where you want implement changes . After that Register to the listner and from child activity when require call notifyChage(params) on parent activty . I will post the code as soon as possible. Please go through [this](http://tseng-blog.nge-web.net/blog/2009/02/17/how-implement-your-own-listener-android-java/) for help.